# Making a special constructor inaccessible to users but accessible to std::construct_at

Tags: c++

My code needs a special constructor that `std::construct_at` can use. This works fine if it's public but then it can be accessed by users of the class. If it is private, `std::construct_at` fails. Here's the minimal code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Vec {
public:
    int* const p{};
    const int len{};
    Vec(int len = 1) : len(len), p(new int[len]{}) {}

    // Raw ctor, for use only inside class using std::construct_at to overlay object
    // Doesn't work executed from std::construct_at if private
    Vec(int* p, int len) : p(p), len(len) {}

    Vec& operator=(Vec&& rhs)
    {
        delete[] p;
        std::construct_at(this, rhs.p, rhs.len);    // dtor not needed for this class
        std::construct_at(&rhs, nullptr, 0);        // steal rhs guts and make valid
        return *this;
    }
    // .... Other ctors
    ~Vec() {delete[] p;}
};

int main()
{
    int* pi{};
    Vec x(pi, 0); // ctor accessable to users. Not good.
    Vec a, b(2);
    b.p[1] = 42;
    a = std::move(b);
    std::cout << "a.p[1] " << a.p[1] << " b.p (Null) " << b.p << "\n";
}
```

So I tried creating an empty struct tag (INNER) defined in the private space, but used in the public ctor. This works:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Vec {
    struct INNER {};
public:
    int* const p{};
    const int len{};
    Vec(int len = 1) : len(len), p(new int[len] {}) {}

    // Raw ctor, for use only inside class using std::construct_at to overlay object
    // Doesn't work executed from std::construct_at if private
    Vec(int* p, int len, struct INNER) : p(p), len(len) {}

    Vec& operator=(Vec&& rhs)
    {
        delete[] p;
        std::construct_at(this, rhs.p, rhs.len, INNER{});    // dtor not needed for this class
        std::construct_at(&rhs, nullptr, 0, INNER{});        // steal rhs guts and make valid
        return *this;
    }
    // .... Other ctors
    ~Vec() { delete[] p; }
};

int main()
{
    int* pi{};
    //Vec x(pi, 0, Vec::INNER{}); // not compilable since INNER is private
    Vec a, b(2);
    b.p[1] = 42;
    a = std::move(b);
    std::cout << "a.p[1] " << a.p[1] << " b.p (Null) " << b.p << "\n";
}
```

While this [works](https://godbolt.org/z/v67M4Y5xW) in GCC, CLANG, and MSVC. But it seems odd that `std::construct_at` can use it since INNER is defined in the private segment.  Is `std::construct_at`s use of INNER legit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it seems odd that `std::construct_at` can use it since `INNER` is defined in the `private` segment. Is `std::construct_at`s use of `INNER` legit?

`std::construct_at` by itself only use public interface. it is legit.

[passkey idiom](https://arne-mertz.de/2016/10/passkey-idiom/) has some caveat though, and you are misusing it.

`private` forbids to use the **name** explicitly, but you can use other form (as implicit contructor with `{/*..*/}` or `decltype`, ...) to actually use the thing which should be protected.

You have to protect a little more:

```
class Vec
{
    class Key
    {
        friend Vec; // Who can have the key
        constexpr Key() {} // Not default to avoid non contrainted uniform initialization call (< C++20)
        constexpr Key(const Key&) = default;
    };
public:
    // ...

    // "private", except for those which have the key
    constexpr Vec(int* p, int len, const Key&) : p(p), len(len) {}

    Vec& operator=(Vec&& rhs)
    {
        std::destroy_at(this);
        std::construct_at(this, rhs.p, rhs.len, Key{});
        std::construct_at(&rhs, nullptr, 0, Key{});
        return *this;
    }
    // .... Other ctors
    ~Vec() { delete[] p; }
};
```

Here, only `Vec` can create a `Key`, and it can pass it to any functions

Comment: Excellent! But there are various fixed [errors](https://godbolt.org/z/ze8PT1hcK) in your example. Fix them and I'll mark this as the answer. Also, I've made this change in my "const correct", constexpr 2D matrix class and it works great!

Comment: Typo should be fixed now. feel free to edit if I miss one.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong about it. When you define a `INNER` class in the private scope of an `OUTER` class, the only thing you are not allowed is manually using the name of `INNER` class outside of of `OUTER`.

Assuming you have a class like:

```cpp
class OUTER {
    class INNER {};
public:
    INNER create_inner() { return INNER{}; }
};
```

So you are not allowed to do:

```cpp
int main() {
    OUTER::INNER inner{};
}
```

However, you can always do:

```cpp
int main() {
    auto inner = OUTER{}.create_inner();
}
```

---

## Note:

In your code, while user are not allowed to do `Vec x(pi, 0, Vec::INNER{})` anymore, they are free to use it like `Vec x(pi, 0, {})`.

Comment: Good point. Is there any way to better hide this ctor from users and still work or some other approach that accomplishes the same?

Comment: @doug: [passkey idiom](https://arne-mertz.de/2016/10/passkey-idiom/) has some caveat as this one. need some `private` and `friend`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for the passkey link. I hadn't seen that before. I could put the special ctor uder private and use placement new which also works but loses the ability to make all this stuff in constexpr. construct_at has special constexpr dispensation. Probably I'm just going to use a stronger struct name like FOR_INTERNAL_USE_ONLY. Won't keep people from using it but will notify them they shouldn't.